# Ansible - win_package MSI Issues

Tags: ansible, windows-installer

Im trying to automate an MSI installer using Ansible.  The MSI performs a lot of the steps but then calls DbTool.exe which opens another CMD window and does a bunch of DB stuff, once complete its closes and the MSI resumes.

When I manually run the below from CMD, its successful:

```
msiexec.exe /i "Package.msi" /quiet /L*V "PackageInstall.log" ISQLSERVER=(local) ISQLAUTH=sql ISQLUID=sa ISQLPWD=********
```

However, when I do the same from Ansible the play hangs when the MSI executes Dbtool.exe.  I can see it Running in Task Manager but isnt doing anything. When the DBtool executes theres no interaction needed unless theres exceptions when running. The Dbtool.exe creates logs but unfortutantley theres no logs as I dont think its getting far enough to start.

```
- name: Installing Package
  win_package:
    path: "{{ Generic_Temp_Path }}\\Package\\{{PackageLatestVersion.stdout}}\\Package64_CTI.msi"
    arguments: /L*V "{{ Generic_Temp_Path }}\Package\{{PackageLatestVersion.stdout}}\PackageInstall.log" ISQLSERVER={{ UT_DB_Servername }} ISQLAUTH={{ UT_DB_SA_Auth }} ISQLUID={{ UT_DB_SA_User }} ISQLPWD={{ UT_DB_SA_Pass }}" 
    wait_for_children: yes
```

Here is the MSI Log, not a lot to see other than its ran it and waiting:

MSI (s) (5C:04) [09:27:36:132]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=Database.NUI_CreateDB,Description=Creating database...,)
MSI (s) (5C:04) [09:27:36:132]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=Database.NUI_CreateDB,ActionType=9298,Source=C:\Program Files\Package\Utilities\DbTool\DbTool.exe,Target=**********,)

The play is running under AdminUser and is the same account I use to manually run the silent installer from CMD so I dont believe its account related.

Ive asked my dev to add some debugging to the dbtool.exe to maybe see if its hanging at some point but from the current logging, theres nothing to go from.

Has anyone come across this before and know any steps to move forward with debugging?

Many Thanks,

Brad.